# When setting onclick using Javascript, the onclick code is running

Tags: javascript

When clicking on a Div, it should change the text in the div (which is done using innerHTML) but I also want to change the onclick function of the div

Here is my JS code

```
document.getElementById('select_image').onclick = document.upload.submit();
```

When clicking on the div, instead of clicking on a hide file upload div (which  it did before) it's submitting the form straight away

If I press back on the browser, it shows the div with the updated text

Thanks

Edit: doesn't look very clear

I have a div (select_image) and when clicking on it, it uses JS (.click) on a hidden input file element so you can select a file.

This div is using onclick="function()" to run a function that changes the text in that div, and I also want it to change the onclick event to actually submit the form this time (as opposed to clicking on the hidden file input) when a file has been selected.

I'm using an onchange="" event to run the following JS function on the file input

```
function selected_image(image) {
    document.getElementById('select_image').innerHTML = 'click here to upload <span id="selected">' + image.replace('C:\\fakepath\\', '') + '</span>';
    document.getElementById('select_image').onclick = document.upload.submit();
}

<div id="select_image" onclick="document.forms['upload'].elements['image'].click();">click here to select your image</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: Provide a sample of your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parentheses in `submit();` causes immediate execution of the function. Now you're trying to assign the return value from `submit` to `onclick` property. A working solution would be to use an anonymous function to handle the event.

```
document.getElementById('select_image').onclick = function () {
    document.upload.submit();
    return;
}
```

Comment: That won't work. When `onclick` gets executed, `this` will be the select_image and not `upload`, so submit will try to submit something that can't be submitted.